# Hints to calculate in a closed form $\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi k x)x^Ne^{-Nx}dx$, for integers $k,N\geq 1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

Let $k\geq 1$ an integer and $N\geq 1$, also an integer. I would like to know hints to get in a closed-form (I believe that it is possible find it) for $N\geq 1$ $$\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi k x)x^Ne^{-Nx}dx.$$

I know that I need define a definite integral $$I_{k,N}$$ integration by parts (what?, it isn't required prove the recurrence that one should deduce from the definition by mathematical induction). I know the first cases.

> **Question.** How one calculate in a closed-form $$\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi k x)x^Ne^{-Nx} dx$$for integers $k,N\geq 1$?

Comment: Consider instead $f(n,a) = \int_0^1 x^n e^{a x}dx$. What do you get for $n=0,n=1,n=2$ ?

Comment: Welcome @user1952009 for $n\geq 0$ is $$\int_0^1 x^n e^{ax}dx=(-a)^{-n-1}(\Gamma(n+1)-\Gamma(n+1,-a)),$$ where the second summand are particular values of the Incomplete Gamma function. Merci.

Comment: That's not what I meant ($\Gamma(s,x)$ is a complicated function, whereas we want a closed-form) Now what do you get when integrating by parts

Comment: **what do you get** when integrating by parts $f(n,a) = \int_0^1 x^n e^{ax}dx$ ?

Comment: Many thnaks @tinlyx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have,  $$\sin (2 \pi k x) = \Im (e^{2 i \pi k x})$$

(where $\Im$ denotes the imaginary part)

so that,

$$ I_{k,N} = \Im \left( \int_{0}^{1} x^N e^{-x (N-2i \pi k )} \ \mathrm{d}x \right)$$

Consider the [Lower Incomplete Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function),

$$\gamma(a,b) = \int_{0}^{b} x^{a-1} e^{-x} \ \mathrm{d}x $$

Substitute $x \mapsto bx$

$$ \implies \gamma(a,b) = b^a \int_{0}^{1} x^{a-1} e^{-bx} \ \mathrm{d}x$$

$$ \implies \int_{0}^{1} x^{a-1} e^{-bx} \ \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{\gamma(a,b)}{b^a} $$

$$ \therefore \ I_{k,N} = \Im \left(\dfrac{\gamma(N+1,N-2ik \pi x)}{(N-2ik \pi x)^{N+2}}\right) $$

---

**Added :** As pointed out in the comments, there is an elementary closed form for $N \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, which can be proved by successive Integration By Parts,

$$ \gamma(a,b) = (a-1)! \left( 1- e^{-b} \sum_{r=0}^{a-1} \dfrac{b^r}{r!} \right) \ \forall \ a \in \mathbb{Z^+} $$

Thus,

$$ I_{k,N} = \Im \left( \dfrac{N!}{(N-2ik \pi x)^{N+2}} \left( 1-e^{-(N-2ik \pi x)} \sum_{r=0}^{N} \dfrac{(N-2ik \pi x)^r}{r!} \right) \right) $$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I am going to study it.

Comment: @Ishan see my comments above there is a closed form when $N \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @user1952009 Added. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @IshanSingh the problem is that I wanted the OP to find it himself..

Comment: @user1952009 No worries, I haven't posted the full proof using IBP, they can do it as an exercise.

Comment: Many thanks one more time for your detailed answer.

Comment: You're welcome!